# Issue sending email with postfix via sendgrid

Tags: postfix-mta, sendgrid, google-compute-engine

I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail to setup postfix to send via sendgrid.  I believe I have it all setup correctly, but mail is failing.  The bounce is not very helpful other than status: 5.0.0 and Action: failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As a wild guess, you might not have run `postmap` from step 5, or reloaded postfix after updating your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.  Can you post the log messages from postfix from `/var/log/syslog` along with your postfix `main.cf`?

One other question: are you running on Debian, CentOS or something else?  I think that the SendGrid instructions you linked to assume Debian, and file locations may be different in CentOS.